# URL design technique

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-2, query-string

My friend designed url tag like : www.aaaa.com/?page=4 in my asp.net mvc2 project, But i want to change my URL like www.aaaa.com/4

so i want to delete ?page tags from my URL.
What can i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The process you're looking for is URL rewriting - you can find the relevant information for ASP.NET here: [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)